# how to search geojson file by an attribute?

Tags: geojson, google-maps, convert, search

### How to search polygon/polyline geojson file by an attribute

I have a geojson file of roads(polyline) having an attribute of road_length now i want to search the geojson file by this(road length) attribute and draw the matched road(polyline) on the google map e-g if i want to draw only those roads having length less than 10 km.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Javascript and have a variable `data` as your `.geojson` with [this](http://geojson.org/) format then you can access the data in a GeoJSON file like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var feature = data[i];
    if (feature['type'] == "Polyline") {
        if (feature['properties']['road_length'] > 10) {
            // draw Polyline
        }
    }
}
```